# Virtual SAN hardware and software

Tags: virtualization, storage, storage-area-network

We are looking into SAN storage. I have been reading up on it for the last couple of months.

We will probably purchase some consulting. For the time being, can anyone suggest a way I could familiarize myself with the process of administrating a SAN without actually having the hardware?

Comment: You do know that every SAN has a different interface don't you? the only commonality is the use of a screen, keyboard and sometimes mouse - you could practice using those if you like - otherwise you might need to narrow down your selection.

Comment: I suppose some intricacies like zoning and managing volumes on the server side is what I'd focus on. Thank you Chopper3. Going to give a go to Starwind's product and NetApp's simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look into the NetApp Data ONTAP Simulator, if you can.

http://communities.netapp.com/docs/DOC-1034

Answer (score 5):

You can very easily set up a small SAN environment in VMware or virtualization tool of your choice. I got started by downloading [openfiler](http://www.openfiler.com/) and installing it in a VM, but there are many other choices, including [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/), roll your own with Linux or FreeBSD with the file sharing protocols of your choice, and probably lots others.

Comment: And that'll work real well to help the OP administer a NetApp.

Comment: @womble It WILL help them administer a NetApp, or any other SAN on the planet, because it will help them learn about the underlying technologies used in a SAN, and understand some of the things that they will need to worry about, like protocols (iSCSI, NFS, et al), file system types (vmfs, ext3|4, zfs, et al), networking (1Gbps, 10Gbps, MTU, tuning) and client configuration.

Answer (score 2):

HP have a [VSA Appliance](http://h18006.www1.hp.com/products/storage/software/vsa/trial/index.html) that you can run on VMware ESXi for 60 days. You can also get an [OpenFiler appliance](http://www.openfiler.com/community/download/) for ESXi too.

Answer (score 0):

EMC has the celerra VSA for testing as well: http://nickapedia.com/2010/09/12/ubertastic-celerra-uber-vsa-v3-unisphere/